# How does HOD differ from L?

Tags: set-theory

If $L$ is the class of constructible sets and $HOD$ is the class of hereditarily ordinal definable sets, in what ways do they differ?

I know that they do as $L$ is absolute in transitive models of $ZFC$ and $HOD$ isn't.  But does $HOD$ always contain $L$? Is there a simple example of a set that can be in $HOD$ but not in $L$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\mathrm{HOD}$ always contains $L$ because any inner model contains $L$, by absoluteness.

How easy it is to exhibit a difference really depends on your background. For instance, $0^\sharp$, if it exists, is a real that always belongs to $\mathrm{HOD}$ but is not in $L$.

If you are not too comfortable with large cardinals, but know forcing, you may enjoy proving that *any* set is consistently in $\mathrm{HOD}$. This gives you many examples. The argument is actually simple: Just code the set using the continuum function.

To further simplify matters, imagine the set, $X$ is a set of ordinals, say $X\subset\alpha$. By a preparatory forcing (collapsing a few cardinals if necessary), you may assume that a long initial segment of the universe satisfies $\mathsf{GCH}$. Now force adding Cohen subsets of different cardinals so that in the extension $2^{\aleph_{\beta+1}}$ is either $\aleph_{\beta+2}$ or $\aleph_{\beta+3}$ for all $\beta<\alpha$, with $2^{\aleph_{\beta+1}}>\aleph_{\beta+2}$ if and only if $\beta\in X$. This allows you to define $X$ in the extension as the set of $\beta<\alpha$ such that the continuum hypothesis is violated at $\aleph_{\beta+1}$. This shows that $X$ is ordinal definable and therefore, since it is a set of ordinals, it is in $\mathrm{HOD}$. [I use only successor cardinals to do the coding so you can arrange this situation by Easton forcing.]

(For general sets $X$, not necessarily sets of ordinals, code the transitive closure $T$ of $\{X\}$ as above, and then check that $X$ is definable from $T$.)

The argument can be pushed further, using class forcing. The result is that, no matter what it is to begin with, the whole universe $V$ can be made the $\mathrm{HOD}$ of an extension. With some (serious) additional work, one can use this idea to show that $V=\mathrm{HOD}$ is consistent with (extremely) large cardinals.

[For moderately large cardinals, one can prove stronger results, by exhibiting canonical inner models of the large cardinal assumptions under consideration. These canonical models "generalize" $L$ and always satisfy $V=\mathrm{HOD}$ and in fact are subclasses of (true) $\mathrm{HOD}$.]

Comment: Is there some reference for the argument concerning large cardinals?

Comment: Do you mean, that there are canonical inner models? This is what inner model theory is about, there are several surveys on this topic, you may want to start with a paper by Jensen in the Bulletin of symbolic logic.

Comment: I meant the argument that V=HOD is consistent with large cardinals

Comment: If you mean that $V=\mathrm{HOD}$ is consistent with very large cardinals,  there are several papers. See for instance [MR1816602](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1816602) (2001m:03102) Hamkins, Joel David. *[The wholeness axioms and $V=\mathrm{HOD}$](https://mathscinet.ams.org/leavingmsn?url=https://doi.org/10.1007/s001530050169)*. Arch. Math. Logic **40** (2001), no. 1, 1–8.

Comment: OK so this paper kinda blew my mind a bit. Thanks! But just to make sure - this doesn't mean that by assuming e.g the existence of a measurable or supercompact or any other large cardinal we can get a model of V=HOD with that cardinal, right? Is this true?

Comment: For just about any large cardinal notion I know of, yes, this is the case. But I do know of any all-purpose theorem ensuring in abstract that this always happens.

Comment: (In the last comment, "I do know" should be "I don't know", of course. Apologies for the typo.)